# Editar gráfico de barras no R: Ordem dos valores do eixo X - Legenda - Cor das barras - Inserir retas - Inserir comentários

Tags: r, ggplot2

**1 - Contextualização**

Quero construir um gráfico de barras utilizando o `ggplot2`, porém estou tendo dificuldades reunir as informações e fazer a edição do gráfico. Tenho dados da oscilação do fenômeno El niño ([ONI](http://ggweather.com/enso/oni.htm)) classificadas em intervalos. Com isto, gostaria de construir um gráfico como este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao invés usar de áreas, usar barras, invertendo **X** e **Y**, adicionando somente as linhas das classes de intensidade (Fraco, Moderado, Forte e Muito Forte) com suas respectivas legendas (anotações).

**2 - Dados**

Considerando uma amostra com medições de 50 meses dos dados de ONI, sendo variáveis a `Data`, o índice(`ONI`) e a fase do `Fenomeno` (El Nino, Normal e La Niña), disposta em um *data.frame*:

```
ONIenla<-data.frame(Data=c("1950-01-31","1950-02-28","1950-03-31","1950-04-30","1950-05-31","1950-06-30","1950-07-31","1950-08-31","1950-09-30","1950-10-31","1950-11-30","1950-12-31","1951-01-31","1951-02-28","1951-03-31","1951-04-30","1951-05-31","1951-06-30","1951-07-31","1951-08-31","1951-09-30","1951-10-31","1951-11-30","1951-12-31","1952-01-31","1952-02-29","1952-03-31","1952-04-30","1952-05-31","1952-06-30","1952-07-31","1952-08-31","1952-09-30","1952-10-31","1952-11-30","1952-12-31","1953-01-31","1953-02-28","1953-03-31","1953-04-30","1953-05-31","1953-06-30","1953-07-31","1953-08-31","1953-09-30","1953-10-31","1953-11-30","1953-12-31","1954-01-31","1954-02-28"),ONI = c(-1.4,-1.2,-1.1,-1.2,-1.1,-0.9,-0.6,-0.6,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.8,-0.6,-0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.4), Fenomeno = c("La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","Normal","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino"))
```

As classes:

```
classesONI<-data.frame(ClasAno=c("Fraca","Moderado","Forte","MuitoForte"),MimEl=c(0.5,1,1.5,2),MaxEl=c(0.99,1.49,1.99,NA),MimLA=c(-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2),MaxLA=c(-0.99,-1.49,-1.99,NA))
```

**3 - Script atual**

Utilizei duas bibliotecas a ´ggplot2´ e a `lubridate`.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(lubridate)
 dados$Data<-ymd(dados$Data)
 grafico<- ggplot(ONIenla,aes(x=Data,y=ONI,guide=F)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge',aes(color=Fenomeno, group=1)) +   coord_flip() + ggtitle("Índice oceâncico Niño (ONI)") + scale_fill_hue('Legenda') +  scale_x_date() + theme(panel.grid.major = lement_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

que resulta em:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**4 - Edições**

Qual a forma de:

- inserir legenda das fases: El Niño, La Niña e Normal;
- editar a cor das barras: El Niño=Vermelho, La Niña= Azul e Normal= Verde;
- inserir as linhas das classes e suas anotações próximas a elas (dica: verificar na gráfico exemplo, as linhas vermelhas e azuis, com suas anotações (*weak, moderate, strong e very strong*);
- inserir um quadro em volta da imagem;
- editar o fundo gráfico para em branco;
- datas ao passo de 5 anos;
- inverter a ordem das datas.

  Grato pelas sugestões.

Comment: conseguirei resolver....

Comment: o que é o objeto `dados` no seu script atual? Não estou conseguindo reproduzir.

Comment: Escrevi com pressa, vou corrigir as gafs. Dados é na verdade ONIenla. E ainda menciono IOS, que é ONI. Isto, aconteceu pois recebi uma dica para mudar o indicador das minha analises, algo que de ultima hora me fez desaperceber estes detalhes. Minhas desculpas!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Já aviso de antemão que tentei responder tua pergunta, mas acabei deixando dois detalhes sem resposta:

- inserir as linhas das classes e suas anotações próximas a elas (não entendi o que isto significa)
- inverter a ordem das datas (procurei exemplos na internet e não fui bem sucedido em encontrá-los)

Caso alguém saiba como fazer isto, por favor, adicione sua contribuição para completar a minha resposta.

Note também que o teu código inicial não era reproduzível. Tomei a liberdade de editá-lo de maneira que fosse possível rodá-lo em meu computador.

Isto posto, segue abaixo meu código.

```
ONIenla <- data.frame(Data=c("1950-01-31","1950-02-28","1950-03-31","1950-04-30","1950-05-31","1950-06-30","1950-07-31","1950-08-31","1950-09-30","1950-10-31","1950-11-30","1950-12-31","1951-01-31","1951-02-28","1951-03-31","1951-04-30","1951-05-31","1951-06-30","1951-07-31","1951-08-31","1951-09-30","1951-10-31","1951-11-30","1951-12-31","1952-01-31","1952-02-29","1952-03-31","1952-04-30","1952-05-31","1952-06-30","1952-07-31","1952-08-31","1952-09-30","1952-10-31","1952-11-30","1952-12-31","1953-01-31","1953-02-28","1953-03-31","1953-04-30","1953-05-31","1953-06-30","1953-07-31","1953-08-31","1953-09-30","1953-10-31","1953-11-30","1953-12-31","1954-01-31","1954-02-28"), ONI=c(-1.4,-1.2,-1.1,-1.2,-1.1,-0.9,-0.6,-0.6,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.8,-0.6,-0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.4), Fenomeno=c("La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","Normal","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino"))

classesONI<-data.frame(ClasAno=c("Fraca", "Moderado", "Forte", "MuitoForte"), MimEl=c(0.5,1,1.5,2), MaxEl=c(0.99,1.49,1.99,NA), MimLA=c(-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2), MaxLA=c(-0.99,-1.49,-1.99,NA))

library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
ONIenla$Data<-ymd(ONIenla$Data)

grafico2 <- ggplot(ONIenla, aes(x=Data, y=ONI, guide=F)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=Fenomeno, color=Fenomeno)) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green")) 
+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green")) 
+ coord_flip() + ggtitle("Índice da oscilação Sul (IOS)") 
+ scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 years", date_labels="%Y") 
+ theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black"))
grafico2
```

[image: Resultado]

Perceba também que não fiz as datas com passo de 5 anos, pois como temos poucos dados, o eixo ficaria meio vazio. Basta alterar a opção date_breaks do comando

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 years", date_labels="%Y")
```

para que tu obtenha o resultado pretendido.

---

Edit: segue o comando completo, com as sugestões do Jean:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

ONIenla <- data.frame(Data=c("1950-01-31","1950-02-28","1950-03-31","1950-04-30","1950-05-31","1950-06-30","1950-07-31","1950-08-31","1950-09-30","1950-10-31","1950-11-30","1950-12-31","1951-01-31","1951-02-28","1951-03-31","1951-04-30","1951-05-31","1951-06-30","1951-07-31","1951-08-31","1951-09-30","1951-10-31","1951-11-30","1951-12-31","1952-01-31","1952-02-29","1952-03-31","1952-04-30","1952-05-31","1952-06-30","1952-07-31","1952-08-31","1952-09-30","1952-10-31","1952-11-30","1952-12-31","1953-01-31","1953-02-28","1953-03-31","1953-04-30","1953-05-31","1953-06-30","1953-07-31","1953-08-31","1953-09-30","1953-10-31","1953-11-30","1953-12-31","1954-01-31","1954-02-28"), ONI=c(-1.4,-1.2,-1.1,-1.2,-1.1,-0.9,-0.6,-0.6,-0.5,-0.6,-0.7,-0.8,-0.8,-0.6,-0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.0,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.4), Fenomeno=c("La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","La Nina","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","Normal","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino","El Nino"))

classesONI <- data.frame(ClasAno=c("Fraca", "Moderado", "Forte", "MuitoForte"), MimEl=c(0.5,1,1.5,2), MaxEl=c(0.99,1.49,1.99,NA), MimLA=c(-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2), MaxLA=c(-0.99,-1.49,-1.99,NA))

ONIenla$Data <- ymd(ONIenla$Data)

grafico2 <- ggplot(ONIenla, aes(x=Data, y=ONI, guide=F)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=Fenomeno, color=Fenomeno)) 
+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green")) 
+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green")) 
+ coord_flip() + ggtitle("Índice da oscilação Sul (IOS)") 
+ scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 years", date_labels="%Y") 
+ theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black")) 
+ geom_hline(yintercept =c(0.5,1,1.5,2,0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2), color="grey") 
+ annotate("text", x=ONIenla$Data[24], y=classesONI$MimEl, label=classesONI$ClasAno, angle=90, vjust=1,fontface = "bold") 
+ annotate("text", x=ONIenla$Data[24], y=classesONI$MimLA,label=classesONI$ClasAno, angle=90, vjust=-.55,fontface = "bold") 
+ ggtitle("Índice oceânico Niño")

grafico2
```

[image: Resultado Final]

Comment: Estás quase lá. Sobre os detalhes, no que se refere as classes e como exibi-las, da uma olhadinha figura exemplo. Verás linhas horizontais que indicam as classes (*weak, modorate, strong, very strong*), é isto, gostaria destas linhas, mas neste caso verticais com suas anotações. Peço desculpa pelas **gafs** no código, tive de alterar as pressas o índice e não percebi os erros, vou corrigir. Boa sorte! Agradecido até o momento.

Comment: Acho interessante realizar algumas alterações na resposta. Adicione os comandos do gráfico: `geom_hline(yintercept =c(0.5,1,1.5,2,0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2),color="grey")` ; `annotate("text", x=ONIenla$Data[24], y=classesONI$MimEl,label=classesONI$ClasAno, angle=90, vjust=1,fontface = "bold")`;`annotate("text", x=ONIenla$Data[24], y=classesONI$MimLA,label=classesONI$ClasAno, angle=90, vjust=-.55,fontface = "bold")`.  E altere o título: `ggtitle("Índice oceânico Niño")`. Tentei incorporar isso em **Edição**, mas acho que não consegui transmitir minha mensagem ao revisor.